# Calculating Rolling forward averages with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I need to calculate some rolling forward averages in a dataframe and really don't know where to start.

I know if I wanted to select a cell 10 days ahead say I would do `df.shift(-10)`, but what I'm looking to do is calculate the average between 10 and 15 days ahead say.

So what I'm kind of thinking is `df.rolling(-10,-15).mean()`, if I was trying to calculate just a moving average going backing in time df.rolling(15, 10).mean() would work perfectly and I did think about just calculating the averages like that, and then somehow shifting the data.

Any help would be great

Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could calculate the rolling mean 5 days ahead, and then [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) that for 10 more periods. Since negative values in [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) are not allowed, you can invert the axis, calculate backwards, and then invert again (see [How to use Pandas rolling_* functions on a forward-looking basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820292/how-to-use-pandas-rolling-functions-on-a-forward-looking-basis)):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 2))
df[::-1].rolling(5).mean()[::-1].shift(-10)
```

Comment: Ahhh I can shift at the end! I didn't know this, yes that's a great answer, that's exactly what I'm after thanks mate

Answer (score 3):

The above answer doesn't look right. IMHO you musn't reverse and shift.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(100, 2))) # int easier to interpret
df[::-1].rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).mean()[::-1]
```

this also works but you lose the last 4 values:

```
df.rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).mean().shift(-5)
```

The more difficult problem of a rolling window that is arbitrarily shifted (offset) probably needs to use .shift() in some way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new method to deal with this. That said includes current row.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer.html

```
indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=2)

df.rolling(window=indexer, min_periods=1).sum()
```