# pandas rolling window that includes 'n' preceding rows and 'm' following rows

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas, how can I write a [rolling window](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) that has preceding as well as following rows?

for example, a sql rolling window can be written as follows:

```
sum(id_0) over (partition by id_1 order by id_2 rows between 3 preceding and 1 following)
```

i am not sure how to write this in pandas.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the rolling sum for 4 preceding values then use the [shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html?highlight=shift#pandas.DataFrame.shift) method to apply those values to one row prior - for example:

```
rolling_ds = dataset.rolling(4, min_periods=1).sum().shift(-1)
```

A more robust discussion of this approach can be found here: [Calculating Rolling forward averages with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55758035/calculating-rolling-forward-averages-with-pandas)